# SVG - Animation Problems

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, smil

I have some shapes which I rotate using two buttons, one for clockwise and the other for anti-clockwise direction:

```js
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

function cwAnim(evt) {
  if (window.svgDocument == null)
    svgDoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;

  addRotateTransform('someShape', 1, -1, 180);
  addRotateTransform('shape1', 1, 1, 360);
  addRotateTransform('shape2', 1, 1, 360);
}

function acwAnim(evt) {
  if (window.svgDocument == null)
    svgDoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;

  addRotateTransform('someShape', 1, 1, 180);
  addRotateTransform('shape1', 1, -1, 360);
  addRotateTransform('shape2', 1, -1, 360);
}

function addRotateTransform(target_id, dur, dir, angle) {
  var my_element = svgDoc.getElementById(target_id);
  var a = svgDoc.createElementNS(svgNS, "animateTransform");

  var bb = my_element.getBBox();
  var cx = bb.x + bb.width / 2;
  var cy = bb.y + bb.height / 2;

  a.setAttributeNS(null, "attributeName", "transform");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "attributeType", "XML");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "type", "rotate");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "dur", dur + "s");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "repeatCount", "1");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "freeze");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "additive", "sum");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "accumulate", "sum");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "from", "0 " + cx + " " + cy);
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "to", angle * dir + " " + cx + " " + cy);

  my_element.appendChild(a);
  a.beginElement();
}
```

```html
<svg width="600px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <circle stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="468.451" cy="474.385" r="350" />
  <g id="someShape">
    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="468.451" cy="474.385" r="350" />
    <path id="shape1" fill="#DC5A00" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M692.373,317.798C692.373,418.425,606.244,500,500,500
   c-106.245,0-192.374-81.575-192.374-182.202c0-100.629,86.128-182.204,192.374-182.204
   C606.244,135.595,692.373,217.169,692.373,317.798z M553.391,220.34c-39.316,0-71.188,31.87-71.188,71.187
   s31.871,71.187,71.188,71.187c39.314,0,71.186-31.87,71.186-71.187S592.705,220.34,553.391,220.34z" />
    <path id="shape2" fill="#3DFF63" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M577.368,647.034c0,69.738-56.913,126.271-127.119,126.271
   c-70.206,0-127.119-56.533-127.119-126.271c0-69.737,56.913-126.271,127.119-126.271
   C520.455,520.764,577.368,577.297,577.368,647.034z M466.352,617.373c-21.998,0-39.831,17.453-39.831,38.983
   c0,21.529,17.833,38.982,39.831,38.982s39.831-17.453,39.831-38.982C506.182,634.826,488.349,617.373,466.352,617.373z" />
  </g>
  <g onclick="cwAnim(evt)">
    <rect x="89.762" y="815.369" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="217.865" height="134.426" />
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 127.4673 864.5491)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="21">AntiClockwise</text>
  </g>
  <g onclick="acwAnim(evt)">
    <rect x="692.373" y="815.369" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="194.11" height="134.426" />
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 752.0576 869.467)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="21">Clockwise</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

You can also see it on this CodePen: http://codepen.io/Daolagajao/pen/qdyBLo

When I click once, the shape animates fine. **The problem arises when I click on the buttons in quick successions** (double click, triple click, etc). The axis of rotation shifts and that is certainly not desirable.

Is there a way around this problem? Something like when i click on the next button, the previous animation in progress stops retaining the position and the new animation takes place.

Comment: Woops updated with snippet now. Looking at it.

Comment: On my machine it goes the wrong way round. It's all a bit eccentric.

Comment: @QuentinUK Ah yes, so does mine (didn't even notice that). But thats matter of just switching the functions around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding a `busy` variable you can indicate that you are currently animating and you shouldn't do any animations. You can do more with this, but it fixes the basic issue.

```js
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var busy = false;

function animationDelegate(evt, direction){
    /* Check if we are busy before doing anything.*/
    /* If we are, stop executing this request, otherwise, set busy to true.*/
    if(busy) return; else busy = true;
    if(direction === 'cw') cwAnim(evt);
    else if(direction === 'ccw') acwAnim(evt);
    /* Your duration is 1 second, so 1000ms.*/
    /* Set a timeout that resets busy.*/
    setTimeout(function(){ busy = false}, 1000);
}

function cwAnim(evt){
  if ( window.svgDocument == null)
    svgDoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;

  addRotateTransform('someShape', 1, -1, 180);
  addRotateTransform('shape1', 1, 1, 360);
  addRotateTransform('shape2', 1, 1, 360);    
}

function acwAnim(evt){
  if ( window.svgDocument == null)
    svgDoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;

  addRotateTransform('someShape', 1, 1, 180);
  addRotateTransform('shape1', 1, -1, 360);
  addRotateTransform('shape2', 1, -1, 360);       
}

function addRotateTransform(target_id, dur, dir, angle){
  var my_element = svgDoc.getElementById(target_id);
  var a = svgDoc.createElementNS(svgNS, "animateTransform");

  var bb = my_element.getBBox();
  var cx = bb.x + bb.width/2;
  var cy = bb.y + bb.height/2;

  a.setAttributeNS(null, "attributeName", "transform");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "attributeType", "XML");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "type", "rotate");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "dur", dur + "s");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "repeatCount", "1");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "freeze");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "additive", "sum");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "accumulate", "sum");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "from", "0 "+cx+" "+cy);
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "to", angle*dir+" "+cx+" "+cy);

  my_element.appendChild(a);
  a.beginElement();
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="600px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve">
  <circle stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="468.451" cy="474.385" r="350" />
  <g id="someShape">
    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="468.451" cy="474.385" r="350" />
    <path id="shape1" fill="#DC5A00" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M692.373,317.798C692.373,418.425,606.244,500,500,500
   c-106.245,0-192.374-81.575-192.374-182.202c0-100.629,86.128-182.204,192.374-182.204
   C606.244,135.595,692.373,217.169,692.373,317.798z M553.391,220.34c-39.316,0-71.188,31.87-71.188,71.187
   s31.871,71.187,71.188,71.187c39.314,0,71.186-31.87,71.186-71.187S592.705,220.34,553.391,220.34z" />
    <path id="shape2" fill="#3DFF63" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M577.368,647.034c0,69.738-56.913,126.271-127.119,126.271
   c-70.206,0-127.119-56.533-127.119-126.271c0-69.737,56.913-126.271,127.119-126.271
   C520.455,520.764,577.368,577.297,577.368,647.034z M466.352,617.373c-21.998,0-39.831,17.453-39.831,38.983
   c0,21.529,17.833,38.982,39.831,38.982s39.831-17.453,39.831-38.982C506.182,634.826,488.349,617.373,466.352,617.373z" />
  </g>
  <g onclick="animationDelegate(evt, 'ccw')">
    <rect x="89.762" y="815.369" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="217.865" height="134.426" />
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 127.4673 864.5491)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="21">AntiClockwise</text>
  </g>
  <g onclick="animationDelegate(evt, 'cw')">
    <rect x="692.373" y="815.369" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="194.11" height="134.426" />
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 752.0576 869.467)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="21">Clockwise</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Not a viable solution. It disables the other rotation functions

Comment: You can always move the solution into the specific functions instead of the main function.

Comment: I tried moving it to the click functions but that disables everything after the first rotation. Maybe it is something that i am doing wrong, can you show how it was meant to be done?

Comment: Before I do that, I have to ask: Whats the problem with disabling other animation functions for a moment? You want to only do another animation _after_ the current one has finished, right? Otherwise you can get weird results _anyway_. No matter _what_ animation.

Comment: Well, let me try to explain it again. What I want is, when i click the CW/ antiCW button, i want all the 3 rotate functions to execute BUT i want to disable/queue another click event. So that while all the animations supposed to execute in one click event runs fine, but it is not interfered by another click event called during the execution of the animation. I hope I could make myself problem a bit more clear.

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao I edited my post, like I said, you can move the `busy` into the calling functions - practically you are wrapping all your animation between settings `busy` to true and setting it back to `false`. When its busy, neither function will respond to clicks. I am also adding a more convenient method. [Update: Convenient method added, is now `animate()`. Animate controls animation delegations and click referral.]

Comment: No, I just tested it again after your comment and the snippet is working on my end. Multiple clicks are disabled and the animation is occurring.

Comment: Sorry, but I is not working on my end. Tried in Chrome and IE. Maybe you could give me a pen link

Comment: Ow thats strange, Chrome throws an error. Let me see. It works is Safari.

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao Turns out `animate` is reserved in SVG language stuff. I renamed it `animationDelegate` and it now functions in Chrome.

Comment: Wow, works exactly as i wanted it to. Thanks for the help, and sorry for all the trouble.